# movement of the rotated camera relative to space

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using react-three.
I want to bind the camera to the player's position and I want to rotate the camera, but then the camera moves along its coordinate system (rotated), I want its position to change in the world coordinate system. How can I do it? Camera position also depends on fov.

```js
export const Player = React.memo((props) => {

  const {camera} = useThree()
  const mesh = useRef()
  const [fov, setFov] = useState(100)

  const distance = 5;

  useFrame(() => {
    camera.near = (1 / camera.fov) * 10
    camera.far=10000
    let init_depht_s = Math.tan(75 / 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0) * 2.0;
    let current_depht_s = Math.tan(camera.fov / 2.0 * Math.PI / 180.0) * 2.0;
    camera.position.set(
      (mesh.current.position.x + ((mesh.current.position.x - distance)*-1)) * init_depht_s / current_depht_s,
      (mesh.current.position.y + ((mesh.current.position.y - distance)*-1)) * init_depht_s / current_depht_s,
      (mesh.current.position.z + distance) * init_depht_s / current_depht_s
    )
    camera.fov = fov
    
    camera.lookAt(mesh.current.position)

    camera.updateMatrixWorld()
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  })

  return <mesh
    {...props}
    ref={mesh}
    scale={1}
    rotation={new Euler((0).toRad(), (0).toRad(), (0).toRad())}
  >
    <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]}/>
    <meshStandardMaterial color={`hsl(0,100%,50%)`}/>
  </mesh>
})
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it solved my problem

```js
...
const newLoc = new Vector3(
mesh.current.position.x + distance * init_depht_s / current_depht_s,
mesh.current.position.y + distance * init_depht_s / current_depht_s,
mesh.current.position.z + distance * init_depht_s / current_depht_s
)
camera.position.copy(newLoc)
camera.lookAt(mesh.current.position)
...
```